# Is ‘affinative’ a word?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word, lexicon

The Microsoft .NET Framework API¹ has a curiously named interface [`ILogicalThreadAffinative`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.ilogicalthreadaffinative). According to their naming standard, namely concatenating capitalized meaningful English words into a single string, this represents something which is “logical thread *affinative*” (and the prefix “I” is for “interface”, which is irrelevant to this question), or, how I read it, *affinative* to a logical thread.

While the meaning of the “logical thread” is clear to the user², I am curious what could the word *affinative* mean, and is this not an invented word at all. To me, it looks like a two-stage suffixal defivation:

*affine* (adj.) > *?affinate* (adj.) > *?affinative* (adj.),

but I cannot find either of the latter two words in any dictionary, or even Google. I have been in this business for 30 years, give or take a few, and never heard them. Also, as documented, the concept is nothing more than being simply *affine* to a logical thread; the entity having this property simply “sticks” to the logical thread and follows it as it spans physical threads³.

**Is the word *affinative* (and/or *affinate*) is, well, a meaningful word? And if it is, how is it different from *affine*?**

---

**Update:** From @ZebraFish's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/459680/173639) it appears the correct spelling of the adjective is *affinitive*, and, by extension, that my own use of *affine* (including this post) in the sense “exhibiting affinity” is probably not correct or, at the very least, is not the best word choice.

---

¹ For the inquisitive but uninitiated, the acronym API, or Application Programming Interface, in this context means a very general set of programming functions for anyone writing a program to use. Usually, at this scale, when such a set is designed for literally tens of millions of users, the API design passes a long, stringent, iterative review for consistency, well-defined behavior and, not the least, naming. I would not even bother asking this question if the case in point was a set of narrow purpose functions developed by a small project (I have seen much worse), but this one is a general-purpose interface to a very popular, flagship platform from a very large company. This is why I am in doubt.
² Understanding what is a *(logical) thread* is probably not essential here. Simply speaking, it is merely a programmed sequence of actions that is *logically* causal and continuous, but *physically* executes on different parts of a computer or even different computers at different times.
³ To give an analogy, suppose you read a Kindle book on your phone, put it down, then later open the same book on a tablet and continue reading where you left off. The page number where you stopped and then continued goes along with, or is *affine* (or “affinative”??) to the “logical thread” of reading the book.

Comment: To me it looks like a spelling error.  Should be "affinitive".

Comment: @HotLicks Right though you may well be, OED nonetheless glosses *affini**ta**tive* with an extra syllababble.

Comment: @tchrist - OED is just being syllie.

Comment: @HotLicks I've just checked after seeing tchrist's comment, there seems to be "affinitative" and "affinitive" just as there are "preventative" and "preventive". Boy, is there a lot to answer for.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry, I misunderstood your point. You're right, it should be "affin-I-tive, not affin-A-tive. Edit: Or alternatively/alternately (hehe) affinitative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"affin-I-tive" yes, "affin-A-tive no, but see the the final note in my answer.

> Affinitive
>  a. 1.  Closely connected, as by affinity.
>   [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Affinitive)
>
> affinitive
>  closely related: a situation affinitive to his own
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affinitive)
>
> affinitive
>  noun
>  An affinity, relationship, or connection.
>   adjective
>  1Characterized by affinity or mutual attraction.
>   2Closely connected or related.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/affinitive)

The last definition lists it also as noun, strangely enough. But it's in nearly all dictionaries I usually check. I'm surprised you didn't find it.

User tchrist pointed out there is also affinitative. I've checked definitions and it seems to be a variant spelling of affinitive.
[affinitative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/affinitive)

Notice the same pattern of variant spellings in:

- preventive/preventative (both acceptable)
- interpretive/interpretative (both acceptable)
- exploitive/exploitative (possibly some opposition to the first spelling)
- authoritive/authoritative (likely opposition to the first spelling)

As to the word "affine", the only context I've heard this word used in is in the term "affine transformation" used in maths. Some definitions only list this term in a specialised context such as maths or anthropology. The following dictionaries do this:

> affine
>  adjective
>  Mathematics
>  Allowing for or preserving
>   parallel relationships.
>  noun
>  Anthropology
>  A relative by
>   marriage.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/affine)
>
> affine
>  adj. Mathematics
>   1. Of or relating to a transformation of coordinates that is equivalent to a linear transformation followed by a translation.
>   2. Of or relating to the geometry of affine transformations.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/affine)
>
> affine
>  adj (Mathematics) maths of, characterizing, or involving
>   transformations which preserve collinearity, esp in classical
>   geometry, those of translation, rotation and reflection in an axis
>   [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/affine)

Some dictionaries define "affine" in a generalised context and not as word specific to an academic field. However if you search in the above dictionaries for the past participle form of affine, that is, "affined", you'll get the following entries:

> adj.
>   1. Linked by a close relationship.
>   2. Beholden to another; bound.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/affined)
>
> adj
>  closely related; connected
>  [Collins English
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/affined)

Two points I want to make. This phenomenon of a dictionary defining an inflected form of a verb, such as past participle, separate from the headword/lemma isn't all that common, but occurs when in its inflected form it has a meaning that can't easily be inferred from the meaning of the headword/lemma form. I can't think of a past participle example, but I can think of:

- certify/certifiable

certifiable to mean crazy or insane may be listed as a separate entry from certify, which may not include the definition of "to declare insane". This is despite the common knowledge of what the suffix -able does. I'll add any better examples if I think of any.

Secondly, I'm sure you know that in certain fields words are used that won't be found in many dictionaries or are unknown by the general public, for example programmers use "performant". In this vein, given that the real word is "affinitive" and not "affinative", the "affinative" in "ILogicalThreadAffinative" may either be a mispelling or their own in-house spelling. I'm guessing this relates to [Processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) which has to do with threads.

Comment: You missed [*affinitative*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/3413).

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, I'm kind of fleshing out my answer. Edit: Oh dear, there is affinitative and affinitive. I assume this follows the same pattern as preventative and preventive, both of which are acceptable. I'll try get to that.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now! Never heard this word. It should be a denominal adjective from *affinity* then. Perhaps my own use of *affine* in the same sense is not strictly correct.

Comment: The *performant* I know, and researched it's origin a while ago. Curiously, it is also traceable to the software engineering jargon at Microsoft. Usually programs are *performant*, not programmers.

Comment: The only reason that “programmers” use *performant* is because they are caught up in corporate business jargon which casts an illusion that it’s both hip and also meaningful in some special way that “performs well” or simply *efficient* is not.

Comment: @tchrist, I do not think it is correct to trace the etymology of this word to business/corporation lingo. The hackers' jargon has a long and respectable cultural history; [*The Jargon File*](http://catb.org/jargon/html/) has a good introduction on the topic. As you indeed know, *performance* is a technical term, and *performant* is a very natural colloquial shortening of "high-perfomance." From my experience, when I have to listen the pointy-hairs, I'm often wondering if they are even speaking English. At the same time, *performant* sounds quite transparent to me.

Comment: @kkm The Jargon File is a good reference.

Comment: I read your updated answer, and also updated the question noting my probable misuse of “affine” in the same sense. Thanks again, I learned a new word today. And you are correct, the concept is similar to that of processor affinity. I am almost sure this is a misspelling; jargons usually do not work this way. I see many of these i/a/e variations in informal writing (mostly where the ubiquitous now spellcheckers are not available, e. g. code comments). It's a common phenomenon in English, since in this position all three vowels reduce to a schwa in speech.