# Etymology of "boy" as an exclamation/interjection

Tags: etymology, interjections

In the sentence "Boy, is there a lot to answer for" (from a recent [EL&U comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459679/is-affinative-a-word#comment1107760_459679)), "boy" is [used for *expressing a strong reaction, especially admiration or excitement*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/boy_2).

How did this meaning/usage come about?  It doesn't seem to be some sort of minced oath, and an association with the pejorative term "boy", used to mean "black male", seems a bit far-fetched.

**The suggested dupe** fails to satisfactorily explain the origin of the term.  It's easy to explain how "Gee" is a minced version of "God", but I don't see such a pathway for "boy".  And the condescending sense suggested doesn't explain why "Oh, boy" expresses pleasure or excitement.

Comment: [The first mention of "Boy!" as an interjection of American origin expressing shock, surprise or excitement listed by the Oxford English Dictionary dates from 1917](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/55/messages/510.html)

Comment: Funny there's no "girl", "sister", "woman".

Comment: @Zebrafish Someone on ubi's dupe suggested "[Aaah Zebras!](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/31544/142322)", though. :)

Comment: @Zebrafish ... I wonder how it would go over if I start using "Woman!" in place of "Man!".  I some feminist objects, I will claim I am doing it to make up for using "Man!" all these years.

Answer (score 0):

**boy** as exclamation

> Emphatic exclamation: oh, boy attested from 1892.

[etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/boy)

in [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/22323?rskey=47b5Vq&result=23#eid128531016):

B. int. colloq. (orig. U.S.).  Frequently as oh boy! ; also as boy oh boy!

> Expressing shock, surprise, excitement, appreciation, etc. Frequently
>   used to give emphasis to a following statement. as early as 1894

As in:

> 1894   G. Ade Chicago Stories 24   S-s-t! Boy! Same as last time.
>
> Nation (N.Y.) 6 Sept. 1900   These biskits are light as a feather,
>   but, boy, they'd be heavier 'n lead If I thought that my hosses was
>   shiv'rin'.

**Boy**, **oh boy**, **boy oh boy** all saw exclamatory usage as above  ~ 1890.  A agree no association with the pejorative. The exclamatory seems to have evolved de novo.